# Avoid duplicated entries when importing data with Magical Record

Tags: core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using Magical Record to facilitate Core Data operations. Imagine we have a set of json like this, and a Core Data model defined exactly the same:

```
{
    "cars": [
        {
            "name": "Corolla",
            "brand": {
                "name": "Toyota"
            },
            "price": 20000
        },
        {
            "name": "Pirus",
            "brand": {
                "name": "Toyota"
            },
            "price": 50000
        },
        {
            "name": "RAV-4",
            "brand": {
                "name": "Toyota"
            },
            "price": 30000
        },
        {
            "name": "Golf",
            "brand": {
                "name": "VW"
            },
            "price": 40000
        },
        {
            "name": "Polo",
            "brand": {
                "name": "VW"
            },
            "price": 20000
        }
    ]
}
```

Now, if we use Magical Record helper method:

```
- (BOOL) MR_importValuesForKeysWithObject:(id)objectData;
```

or

```
+ (id) MR_importFromObject:(id)data;
```

it will be imported as 5 entries of Car and 5 entries of Brand.

However, in our Core Data model, Car-Brand relationship is a many-to-many one, and Brand's name attribute is supposed to be unique, so I'm expecting 5 entries of Car and 2 entries of Brand (Toyota and VW).

My question is how to maintain the data uniqueness while importing with Core Data. Is this something I can define in Core Data model, like unique attribute? or is it I need to override Magical Record's import method?

Comment: Did you get an answer for this?

Comment: I am pretty sure you will have to solve this problem programmatically based on http://forums.pragprog.com/forums/90/topics/2875 by Marcus S. Zarra

Comment: According to http://www.cimgf.com/2012/05/29/importing-data-made-easy/ it appears you can add a 'relatedByAttribute' key and map it to the property that it should treat as a key...

Comment: By the way, why is is a many-to-many relationship? If you have a `Car` it can only be one brand, there it should be one-to-mant on the relationship from `Brand` to `Car`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell MagicalRecord what is the unique identifier. In your case you have no unique ID, but you could probably use the `name` attribute.

Assuming you have a `Car` NSManagedObject with a relationship to a `Brand` NSManagedObject, you have to set `relatedByAttribute` to `name` on the relationship to the `Brand` in the user info dictionary.

Once you have done this MagicalRecord will look up any records with the attribute `name` and use the appropriate record if one already exists, or create one if needed.

This means you won't have to override important with a category class.

Let me know if you need additional information.